# How do i update the openstack api access to be accessible from the outside world

Tags: openstack

My openstack install is working wonderful, with the exception that all api access URLS are 192.168.x.x ... I have looked through a lot of postings and im still left confused. Which commands do i use to allow openstack to have local lan ip and 'foo.com' (public) api access?

I apologize if this has been posted before, i'm not seeing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On your server hosting keystone check :

```
keystone service-list
```

retrieve the id of the service your looking fo

```
keystone endpoint-list | grep id
```

You'll have three url : public, internal, admin

To change the public url use mysql command like

```
mysql -uroot -p
use keystone;
update endpoint set url="http://publicURL:port/" where id="yourID";
```

Hope it'll help